# SPSite - exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.GetRolesForUser

Tags: spsite

I am trying to open site(FBA enabled with custommembership & customroleprovider) through module/httpmodule. It is throwing error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.GetRolesForUser(String
>   roleManagerName, String userName, UInt32& roleCount, String& roles)

Here is the code:

```
HttpRequest r = HttpContext.Current.Request;
using (SPSite s = new SPSite(r.Url.AbsoluteUri))
                    { ......}
```

Please provide me if there is any solution

Regards.

Comment: I dont know your exact usage, but is it possible to run your code under admin privilege like SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges ?

Answer (score 1):

Diptarag is correct if the user doesnt have access then it will throw that error:

Try the code below instead:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    HttpRequest r = HttpContext.Current.Request; 
    using (SPSite s = new SPSite(r.Url.AbsoluteUri)) 
    { 

    } 
});
```

for further info look here:

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity

it contains a method called RunWithElevatedPrivileges

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx